# Tracing and Debugging in Rand StdGen Monad in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell, random, monads, trace

As something of a Haskell newbie, I've been going through the UPenn Haskell course and working through the homework problems. In order to facilitate debugging, I turn on Tracing with:

```
import Debug.Trace
```

The problem that I have is that I don't quite understand the behavior of one of my programs when tracing is enabled.

In particular, I have been working on the last homework assignment of the Haskell course, in which students are asked to simulate the game of Risk (a popular boardgame in the US) in which 2 players roll dice to play the game.

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/fall14/spring13/hw/12-monads.pdf

In Exercise 2, the assignment calls for writing a function `battle` which takes a `Battlefield` data type and returns a monadic `Battlefield`

```
           battle :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
```

to simulate the result of a single battle in which the attacking player and the defending player roll dice to determine the outcome of the battle.

Then in Exercise 3, we simulate a full invasion, in which round after round of battles are waged until one of the players' armies is too depleted to continue.

```
           invade :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
```

I wrote up the following:

```
invade :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
invade bfield = do
  if battleOver bfield then return bfield
    else battleUntilOver $ battle bfield

battleOver :: Battlefield -> Bool
battleOver bfield
  | attackers bfield < 2        = True
  | defenders bfield == 0       = True
  | otherwise                   = False

battleUntilOver :: Rand StdGen Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battleUntilOver randBfield = do
  bfield <- randBfield
  traceM $ "bfield::" ++ show bfield ++ "::"
  if battleOver bfield then return bfield
    else battleUntilOver $ battle bfield
```

Here is the output:

```
*Risk> evalRandIO $ invade Battlefield {attackers=10,defenders=10}
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 10, defenders = 8}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 8, defenders = 8}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 6, defenders = 8}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 4, defenders = 8}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 4, defenders = 6}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 2, defenders = 6}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 2, defenders = 5}::
Battlefield {attackers = 1, defenders = 5}
```

What I don't understand is why the last round of tracing does not get printed. The function `battleUntilOver` is called recursively until the the result of the `battleOver` function ends the recursion. Thus I would expect the `traceM` function to print out

```
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 1, defenders = 5}::
```

before the `battleOver` function returns True and the game ends. I don't understand why it doesn't.

Also, I have noticed that in the `battleUntilOver` function, if I replace

```
if battleOver bfield then return bfield
```

with

```
if battleOver bfield then randBfield
```

then the program does not work properly, outputting a faulty result.

```
*Risk> evalRandIO $ invade Battlefield {attackers=10,defenders=10}
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 8, defenders = 10}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 7, defenders = 9}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 5, defenders = 9}::
bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 3, defenders = 9}::
Battlefield {attackers = bfield::Battlefield {attackers = 1, defenders = 9}::
3, defenders = 7}
```

The last line is reproduced as I see it in GHCI, in which the tracing output is interspersed into the output of the evaluation of the `invade` function.

Here the program seems to be ending because within the monad, `battleOver` evaluates to True, and

```
[attackers = 1, defenders = 9]
```

ends the game, indicating that the defenders won the last round, yet the evaluated output appears to be

```
[attackers = 3, defenders = 7]
```

a condition in which the attackers had won that round instead (and in which the game should continue).

Why do I have to wrap the pure value `bfield` instead of returning the original monadic value `randBfield`?

Comment: The functions from `Debug.Trace` generally don't offer really _reliable output_. They're just meant as a quick way of seeing “what the heck is going one there”. But what is shown and in which order depends a lot on the evaluation order of your expressions, and since this is Haskell the compiler has _a lot_ of freedoms in reordering that etc.: because of referential transparency, it knows some transformations can't make any difference at all. But `trace` is not referentially transparent. — If you want any sort of reliable logging, you should insert a `WriterT` in your monad stack.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Thanks. That helps answer why the debugging and tracing for the last iteration does not show up. However, I am still uncertain about why replacing `if battleOver bfield then return bfield` with `if battleOver bfield then randBfield` yields an incorrect result. The result  that was returned, `[attackers = 3, defenders = 7]`, should not have ended the recursion.

Comment: Ah. Well that of course _should_ be different. You're generating two different randomised values. It's the whole point of randomness that two subsequent calls to a random action will not give the same result, but merely different samples from a single well-defined random distribution.

Comment: @leftaround. Got it. Thanks. thomie explained it very well below. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

> What I don't understand is why the last round of tracing does not get printed.

You can't "trust" `traceM`. This is the implementation:

```
traceM :: (Monad m) => String -> m ()
traceM string = trace string $ return ()
```

As the documentation  says:

> Note that the application of `trace` is not an action in the monad, as `traceIO` is in the IO monad.

Here is another confusing [example](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-January/019322.html) with `traceM`:

```
import Debug.Trace

f n action = if n > 0
                 then action >> f (n - 1) action
                 else return ()

main = f 4 $ do 
         traceM "traceM"
         traceIO "traceIO"
```

Result when compiled with `-O0`:

```
traceM
traceIO
traceIO
traceIO
traceIO
```

Result when compiled with `-O`:

```
traceM
traceIO
traceM
traceIO
traceM
traceIO
traceM
traceIO
```

That said, I don't exactly know why your code runs all `traceM` statements, except the last one. You would have to investigate the strictness properties of the `Rand StdGen` monad. See for example this [email](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-January/019319.html), where it is shown that `runIdentity $ traceM "test" >>
return ()` doesn't print anything at all, because the `Identity` monad is not strict in the first argument of `>>=`. Since you call `evalRandIO`, which calls `evalRand`, which calls `runIdentity`, this might have something to do with your problem as well.

(someone please update the answer)

### Question 2

> Why do I have to wrap the pure value `bfield` instead of returning the original monadic value `randBfield`?

Maybe if you changed the signature of `battleUntilOver` to take a `Battlefield`, it becomes more clear:

```
invade :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
invade bfield = do
  if battleOver bfield then return bfield
    else battleUntilOver bfield

battleUntilOver :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battleUntilOver bfield = do
  bfield' <- battle bfield
  traceM $ "bfield::" ++ show bfield' ++ "::"
  if battleOver bfield' then return bfield'
    else battleUntilOver bfield'
```

Do you agree this does the same thing as your original program?

Now, you wonder why doing the following didn't give you the same result:

```
battleUntilOver :: Battlefield -> Rand StdGen Battlefield
battleUntilOver bfield = do
  bfield' <- battle bfield
  traceM $ "bfield::" ++ show bfield' ++ "::"
  if battleOver bfield' then battle bfield   -- Here is the change
    else battleUntilOver bfield'
```

When the battle is supposedly over, you are asking for a rematch of the last battle (using the pen-ultimate battlefield)! This final final battle will use different random values, as @leftroundabout said, so it should give you a different result every now and then. Other times, the result will be the same, all depending on the initial seed of the random number generator.